# Simplifying my array elements

Tags: java, arrays

my program is here

```
int row=4,column=3;
int a[][]=new int[row][column];

a[0][0]=1;
a[0][1]=2;
a[0][2]=3;
a[1][0]=4;
a[1][1]=5;
a[1][2]=6;
a[2][0]=7;
a[2][1]=8;
a[2][2]=9;
a[3][0]=10;
a[3][1]=11;
a[3][2]=12;

for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        System.out.println(" ");  

    for (j=0;j<column; j++){
        System.out.print(a[i][j]); 
        System.out.print(" ");
```

instead of using the program above. I would like to put my array this way

```
int row=4,column=3;
int a[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};
```

but I'm having difficulty in printing it like these

```
1 2 3        
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Comment: unclear what is your question ?

Comment: question and code where you print the 2d array

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] on how to as a question.  You will get a better response if you provide all the details.

Comment: are you asking to _simplify_ or _how to print as your desired output_?

Comment: sorry for unclear question. here's my edited FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You just need a nested loop to traverse rows up to bottom and columns left to right like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { // traverse rows
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) { // traverse columns
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " "); // prints element in a(i,j) and a space before the next element

        if (j == cols - 1) System.out.println(""); // if it reached the end of the column, breaks to a new line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It a little unclear of your intentions, but I'm guessing that you're having a problem with lining up your output (space formatting).

If you know (upfront) the largest value in your array then you can format your output with padding, otherwise you have to iterate through your array twice.

- Once to determine the largest value so you'll know how many digits there are
- The second time is to print the results

So you can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int array[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12},{100,101,102}};

    // Determine which number has the most digits to set padding width
    int padding = 1;
    for (int[] row : array) {
        for (int col : row) {
            int strLength = String.valueOf(col).length();
            if (strLength > padding) {
                padding = strLength;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int[] row : array) {
        for (int col : row) {
            // Adding 1 to padding to include spaces
            System.out.print(String.format("%" + (padding + 1) + "d", col));
        }
        // Ends the row 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
  10  11  12
 100 101 102
```

You can see that the largest value has 3 digits, but we pad with 4 to so that every print of a number takes up 4 characters which will space everything evenly apart and is right justified.

### UPDATE

If you're allowed to use Java 8, here's a stream way of determining the largest value in the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {100, 101, 102}, {1001, 1002, 1003}};

    int padding = String.valueOf(Arrays.stream(array).flatMapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a)).max().getAsInt()).length();
    for (int[] row : array) {
        for (int col : row) {
            // Adding 1 to padding to include spaces
            System.out.print(String.format("%" + (padding + 1) + "d", col));
        }
        // Ends the row 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```